# Double Summation over inverse square roots

Tags: summation, radicals

I am working on an error estimate that requires me to compute the following expression:
$$\sum_{i=-n}^{n}\sum_{j=-n}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{i^4+j^4}{n^4a^4}+ \frac{1}{4}}}$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ are constants. I can surely evaluate this on the computer for given $a,n$, but I wonder if this can be brought into a closed-form expression. I have seen some posts here on the summation of inverse square roots, but the arguments are always easier than in this case.

Comment: You might want to add some more context to your question, such as where this question comes from and how big $a$ and $n$ are (approximately).

Comment: I wonder what makes you think it has a closed form. Look at small $n$ for a start.

Comment: @TobyMak For context, see the appendix of this ArXiv paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.01003, where in interesting cases, $n$ varies from several hundreds to several ten-thousands.

Comment: @metamorphy: I don't know whether it has a closed form expression, I was just wondering whether it could be brought into one.